# How can I permanently pair a Wii Balance Board with an Ubuntu PC?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, wii

I have a Wii Balance Board, for which I've written a weight-measuring script ([detailed here](http://www.stavros.io/posts/your-weight-online/)). However, I can't get the board to pair with the computer.

I don't want to have to put it in sync mode every time, as it's very time-consuming, but it won't accept any PIN code I enter. I tried `"000000"`, the host's address in reverse hex (if the host is `00:11:22:33:44:55`, then I tried the PIN `"$554433221100"` with bluez, same with the board's address, neither worked).

Using the built-in Ubuntu Bluetooth wizard fails horribly, though, as, no matter which PIN I specify, it always generates a random one, asks me to enter it and fails half a second later. I tried the above with the `bt-device` utility.

Has anyone managed to pair a balance board (or a wiimote) with Ubuntu (or anything/find the PIN, really)?

Comment: I have doubts about how good of a fit this question is for SO, but I've been hacking with the Oculus Rift lately and the idea of adding in the Wii-Fit as an input sounds amazing. I hope someone here can help.

Comment: Hmm, what would be a better place for it? It's a programming/hardware hacking question. Also, wait until you see what I want to do with the Leap Motion + Oculus Rift.

Comment: I'll admit to not always getting the balance correct here (or on other stack exchange sites). I think it would help if you added the pairing code that was failing and link directly to the libraries you are relying on. As the question currently reads it takes a bit of research to understand all of the moving parts you are working with.

Comment: And I have bookmarked your blog, I can't wait to see what you come up with.

Comment: I just have a balance board and Ubuntu with bluez (ignore the rest, they come in later) and I want to pair it to the computer. You're supposed to use the host's BT address with reversed bytes as the PIN, but it's not working, for some reason...

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that bluez 4.101 doesn't support hex PIN codes. Patching it with the appropriate code and recompiling worked.

Comment: So glad you found your answer, this question has inspired me to dig out my Wii Balance board :)

Comment: Great! If you want, there are instructions on how to pair it in my blog post (link is in the question).

Comment: It looks like the newer Bluez that comes with Ubuntu 18.04 (Bluez 5.48) does not come with the right tools (bluez-test-device', 'bluez-simple-agent' or 'bluez-test-input' scripts). Did you manage to get your code to work with that stack?